# php code is not working,showing Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysq1i_query()

Tags: php

php code is not working,showing

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysq1i_query()

```
<?php
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbuser='root';
$dbpass='';
$conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,"vishal");
$passkey=$_GET['passkey'];
$tblname="data";
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tblname WHERE   confirmcode='$passkey'";
$result=mysq1i_query($sql);
if($result)
{ 
    $count=mysqli_num_rows(($result));
    if($count==1)
    { 
        $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $name=$rows['name'];
        $emailid=$rows['emailid'];
        $password=$rows['password'];
        $confirm=$rows['confirm'];
        $country=$rows['country'];
        $table2="data1";
        $sql2="INSERT INTO $table2 (name,emailid,password,confirm,country)VALUES  ('$name','$emailid','$password','$confirm','$country')"; $result1=mysqli_query($sql2);
    }
    else
    { 
        echo"wrong cofirmation code";
    }
    if($result1)
    { 
        echo"your account has been activated";
        $sql3="DELETE FROM $tblname WHERE   confirm_code='$passkey'";
        $result2=mysqli_query($sql3);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Change this line : `$result=mysq1i_query($sql);` to `$result=mysqli_query($sql);`

Answer (score 2):

you have used on line no: 9

```
$result=mysq1i_query($sql);
```

instead of

```
$result=mysqli_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in this line:

```
$result=mysq1i_query($sql);
```

**Its l not 1 in (mysq1i)**

Correct one is:

```
$result=mysqli_query($sql);
```

And when you get this error **Undefined Function** it means you do not define this function in your code.

Comment: ya got it,by mistake put it 1.